# How to track progress bar status of a java window

Tags: java, jython, progress

My application is created in java and it opens several java windows on invoking a event. I could get the active window using **jython **code:

```
 k = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
 wa = k.getActiveWindow()
 print(wa.getTitle())
```

But, how to get all open java windows ?
And, how to get the status of the progress bar inside the java window?